# MySQL Design Clarification

Tags: php, mysql, sql, facebook, join

I'm new to MySQL but have a pretty solid background in a wide variety of programming languages.

Right now I'm designing my first database from the ground up. I understand the basic functionality of MySQL tables and what a relational database is but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around a few things so I'm posting this for help (searching hasn't worked, the terms I've been using are too general and I don't know how to narrow it down). Here's where I'm stuck:

I want to pull Facebook data, specifically interests ("likes") and user location.

If this were some OO language I would just create a data structure for Users with all of the info in it (Facebook ID, interests as an array, location) but I'm not sure how to recreate this in MySQL.

Right now I'm thinking of creating a **users** table with

- Facebook ID (primary key?)
- Name
- Location
- Join date

Then creating an **interests** table with

- Interest name (index, sorted alphabetically?)
- Maybe a count of users with this interest
- Foreign key that relates back to each user

I think this is where my lack of understanding comes in. How do I replicate the concept of a list or array in MySQL in a way that allows me to map each interest to each user who has "liked" that interest?

Any other suggestions, thoughts, or directions to good tutorial sites are greatly appreciated. I'm a tactile learner so getting my hands dirty with a tutorial would be great for me, I just haven't found one that covers this yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a third table that would link the `interests` table to the `user` table.  There would only be a record if the user liked that interest:

Table **User_Interest**:

```
Interest_ID
User_ID
```

To get a list of a user with all of their interests:

```
SELECT u.Name, i.Interest_Name
FROM Users AS u
INNER JOIN User_Interest AS ui ON ui.User_ID = u.ID
INNER JOIN interests AS i ON i.ID = ui.Interest_ID
WHERE u.Name = 'Tom Jones'
```

To get a list of a particular interest and all users that liked:

```
SELECT u.Name, i.Interest_Name
FROM Users AS u
INNER JOIN User_Interest AS ui ON ui.User_ID = u.ID
INNER JOIN interests AS i ON i.ID = ui.Interest_ID
WHERE i.Interest_Name = 'Hiking'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Linger. A few questions based off your response and the one from Krimson. Would it be OK that multiple users have potentially thousands of interests? Rather, is it expected that I would see a large number of  rows for each User_ID? Is this kind of third mapping table standard for many-to-many relationships?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is standard for linking many-to-many relationships.  It will be able to handle as many records as you INSERT.  So, ***thousands of interests*** should not be a problem.  You are using primary and foreign keys so they will be indexed and help speed things up naturally.

Comment: One other point: In the `User_Interest` table make sure to set a ***Composite key*** on `Interest_ID` and `User_ID` combined.  This will insure you do not get any duplicate liked interest for the same user.  You can see this visually in ***Krimson's*** answer with the `StudentCourseEnrollment` table.

Comment: Good to know, I'll add in the composite key.

Answer (score 1):

This type of setup is called a "many to many" relation. To do this, you will need 3 tables. 2 tables which contain your data and the last table a mapping table.
**Here is an example of a many to many relation ship where the two objects are Students and Courses** 
[image: An example of a many-to-many relation]

---

## Example

**Your user table looks like this:**
`(ID_User, User_Name, ...)`
**Your interest table looks like this:**
`(ID_Interest, Interest_Name, ...)`
**Now your mapping table will look like this:**
`(ID_User, ID_Interest)`

---

## Sample Data

**Now lets put some data in the tables**

```
User_Table
------------------------
ID_user | Username | ...
------------------------
   1       John  
   2       Mark 
   3       Foo
   4       Bar
```

```
Interest_Table
----------------------------------
ID_Interest | Interest_Name | ... 
----------------------------------
   001         Pop
   002         Rock
   003         Alternative
   004         Rap
```

```
User_To_Interest (Mapping Table)
---------------------------
ID_user | ID_Interest
---------------------------
  1          001
  1          003
  3          002
  2          004
  4          001
```

---

## Examining this

Ok so here if you analyze what has been set up, we are mapping users to interests. The mapping table sort of adds wires from the User object to an interest object.